# Stream<String> to Map<String, Integer>

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream, collect, collectors

I have a `Stream<String>` of a file, now i want to combine equal words into a `Map<String, Integer>` which counts, how often the word is in the `Stream<String>`.

I know that I have to use `collect(Collectors.groupingBy(..))`, but i do not know how to use it.

It would be very nice, if there is somebody who can provide some hints how to solve this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite easy to create `Map<String, Long>` using the `Collectors.counting()` as downstream collector:

```
Stream<String> s = Stream.of("aaa", "bb", "cc", "aaa", "dd");

Map<String, Long> map = s.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));
```

If you don't like `Long` type, you can count to `Integer` this way:

```
Map<String, Integer> mapInt = s.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Function.identity(),
        Collectors.reducing(0, str -> 1, Integer::sum)));
```